# Let $V = C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ and $T \in L(V)$ defined by $(T(f))(t)=tf(t)$. Prove that $T$ has no eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V = C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) = \{ f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mid f$ in infinitely many times differentiable $\} $ be a vector space. Let $T \in L(V)$ defined by $(T(f))(t)=tf(t)$. Prove that $T$ has no eigenvalues.

**My attempt**:

> Let $T(f) = \lambda f $ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} $, then $(T(f))(t) = \lambda f(t) $ for all $t \in \mathbb{R} $. Which implies that $tf(t)=\lambda f(t)$ and for non zero function $f$, this gives us $t=\lambda$. But since it should be true for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $T$ has no eigen values.

Is this proof correct? Are there any other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Also, what does it actually mean for a Linear transformation to not have any eigen values? Is it a very special case? Can we say anything about the vector space from this result?

Comment: Your argumentation is correct. Yes, we can say something about the vector space: it is infiite-dimensional. In finite dimensions you always have eigenvalues.

Comment: @amsmath Do you mean "you always have eigenvalues" for this very specific example of linear map, or for *any* map?

Comment: Any linear map in a finite-dimensional space has eigenvalues.

Comment: @amsmath Well, no. Any map represented by a matrix whose characteristic polynomial has no roots on the definition field has no eigenvalues. For example, the linear map $$\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}: \Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$$ has no eigenvalues nor eigenvectors. Yet this can easily be solved by requiring the definition field is algebraic closed, for example.

Comment: @DonAntonio You're centainly right. I was of course thinking of complex spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I think your reasoning is very correct and explicit enough actually. I also think this result would still hold if the functions are not continuous what so ever (as a long as they from a vector space) and as long as it is not just the zero function.* **Not correct, as pointed out below!**

Just for entertainment also notice that the vector space that just contains the zero vector is a vector space, but any linear map defined on it, can not have by definition any eigenvalues.

The main point here is, that as long as the vector space is finite dimensional a lot of nice properties hold for linear maps that are not true at all for infinite dimensional vector spaces and linear maps. One example has to do with the injectivity and surjectivity of a linear map. So any linear map on a finite dimensional vector space is injective if and only if it is surjective. And this fact enters a lot in the discussion of eigenvalues on finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: That is not quite true, we cannot take whatever we like. The space $$ \{ f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \ \vert \ \forall x\neq 0: f(x)=0 \} $$ forms a vector space and all the functions except the constant zero function are eigenfunctions of $T$. You could now argue that this is a stupid example (as the space is finite dimensional), however, if you pick $$ \{ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\} $$ you also get all those eigenvectors from above.

Comment: Yes, thank you, you are very right, I was a bit to careless.

Comment: I like your remark on the zero vector space :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to be more clear and explicit: since $\;f\neq0\;$ (as we assume it is an engenvector), then there exists $\;t_0\in\Bbb R\;$  such that $\;f(t_0)\neq0\implies\;$ there exists a neighborhood $\;I_0\;$ of zero where $\;f\;$ keeps the same sign as $\;f(t_0)\;$ (from continuity), so:

$$t_0f(t_0)=\lambda f(t_0)\implies t_0=\lambda$$

but the above *exactly* will yield $\;\lambda =t\;$ for any $\;t\in I_0\;$, and this is a contradiction.

Comment: Actually, you only need two points where $f$ is not zero.

Comment: @amsmath Actually, I got more from a very basic property of non-zero continuous functions...

Comment: No shit, Sherlock...